# high cpu usage in one core ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I am new to Ubuntu and when I installed in the first day I had this pug of using one core on interrupt gpe0D and I disabled it but today after two days is issue in the image begun it's the same as before but the gpe0D is disabled I checked it and I don't know why this happening can someone help?

EDIT:
nothing consuming the CPU in the processes tab.

[image: CPU usage]

Comment: Go to the processes tab, and check which process is consuming CPU. Then [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1391332/edit) the question with that information.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi nothing consuming CPU

Comment: *"nothing consuming CPU"* - that's really not possible.  Can you edit your question with the requested information so that we can review it? You should record this information when you notice the same behavior as the resource monitor you posted in your screenshot.